# Intellij, Spring: Cannot resolve views after cloning repository

Tags: java, spring, git, jsp, intellij-idea

So I was working on other computer on my project, Spring Boot based btw using IntelliJ. Now I wanted to clone my online repository and run project. Everything works except for resolving views. I get error:
`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`

What could go wrong and how can I fix it?

I'm not using web.xml, it's Spring Boot project. Here's my view resolver config

```
    @Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Check your servlet mapping, it could help. If dispatcher servlet's mapping is not "/" set it

Comment: Am I correct that your project in first rep location is working fine, and second gives you this error? Maybe you have hardcoded paths somewhere (check using 'grep'). And take a look at your run configuration in IDEA